# Typescript - How to type guard the existence of a module when using dynamic import?

Tags: typescript, react-native, dynamic-import

I'm currently using 'react-i18next' and 'i18next-locize-backend') in react native.

I want to use locize differently for each environment(development, production).

For example, in the production environment, I want to use the downloaded translation json file. but in the development environment, I want to receive translation data through backend api on the locize site.

I don't want to download the translation json file in the development environment, but unfortunately, typescript makes a compilation error `Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations.`

How can I prevent that compilation error?

The code below is what I wrote.

```
import i18n, { InitOptions } from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import { isProduction } from '../src/utils'
import { LOCIZE_PROJECT_ID, LOCIZE_API_KEY } from 'react-native-dotenv'

const initOptions: InitOptions = {
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
  debug: false,
  lng: 'en',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
}

if (isProduction) {
  ;(async function () {
    const en = await import('./locales/en-US/translation.json') // where the error occurs.
    
    i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
      ...initOptions,
      resources: { en: { translation: en },
    })
  })()
} else {
  const backendOptions = {
    projectId: LOCIZE_PROJECT_ID,
    apiKey: LOCIZE_API_KEY,
    referenceLng: 'en',
    version: 'latest',
  }

  import('i18next-locize-backend').then(({ default: LocizeBackend }) => {
    i18n
      .use(LocizeBackend)
      .use(initReactI18next)
      .init({ backend: backendOptions, ...initOptions })
  })
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "react-native",
      "lib": ["es2017"],
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noEmit": true,
      "strict": true,
      "module":"ESNext",
      "target": "esnext",
      "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "babel.config.js",
      "metro.config.js",
      "jest.config.js"
    ]
  }
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      {
        moduleName: 'react-native-dotenv',
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

---

node : 14.17.5.
react native : 0.64.1.
i18next : 21.4.2.
react-i18next : 11.14.1.
typescript : 4.4.4.
i18next-locize-backend : 4.2.3

Comment: can you please include your babel config too?

Comment: @Kemal Ahmed I updated it!